# Kotlin Room SUM operation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I need to perform column sum operation
But I don't understand what exactly I need to insert into `fun getSumItem(): Flow<Cursor>`

this is my Dao

```
@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Insert
    fun InsertItem(item: Income)
    @Query("SELECT SUM(sum) AS value FROM income")
    fun  getSumItem(): Flow<Cursor>

}
```

this is my table

```
@Entity(tableName = "income")
data class Income(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var date: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    var type: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sum")
    var sum: Float,


)
```

I did not find a similar example and any detailed information on the Internet.
when I use `Cursor` i get this error:
`Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - android.database.Cursor`

all other options that I found on the Internet also gave errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `SELECT SUM(sum) AS value FROM income` the output that Room handles will be a Cursor with a single column named `value`. Room does not know how to extract this value and build a Cursor object from that single value.

Room expects to extract data from the underlying Cursor that is generated by the SQLite API, which Room is a wrapper to/around, and deliver the data according to the object that the function returns (and thus must be able to ascertain how to build the resultant object).

As Room extracts a single value then you simply need to retrieve the value returned as a Float.

```
fun  getSumItem(): Flow<Float>
```